# output deleted variable from sql query does not work in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this query in my c# asp.net server. When I run it on the server it output the inserted status and not the deleted one as expected. when I run the same query on the Microsoft management SQL studio it works just fine.

Any suggestions for what could be wrong?

```js
public override BaseMessageStatus SetHubMessageStatus(Participant toParticipant, Transaction transaction, Ticket ticket, BaseMessageStatus nextStatus)
        {
            BaseMessageStatus originalStatus = BaseMessageStatus.Undefined;

            SqlConnection sqlConnecntion = SQL_CONNECTION;

            string stquery = @"update [webMessages] set [status]=@status OUTPUT Deleted.status
                               where [sessionId]=@sessionId and [transactionId]=@transactionId and [toPartID]=@toParticipantID";

            //new DataTable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            using (sqlConnecntion)
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stquery))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = sqlConnecntion;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessionId", ticket.id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transactionId", transaction.id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toParticipantID", toParticipant.id);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", (int)nextStatus);

                    try
                    {
                        sqlConnecntion.Open();

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        da.Fill(dt);

                        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (dt.Rows[0]["status"] != null && dt.Rows[0]["status"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                Enum.TryParse<BaseMessageStatus>(dt.Rows[0]["status"].ToString(), out originalStatus);
                            }
                        }

                        sqlConnecntion.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Logger.Error(ex);
                    }
                }
            }

            return originalStatus;
        }
```

Comment: There really isn't enough code to tell what the problem might be. How are you executing the statement? How are you getting the results? (How) have you verified the incoming parameter values are what you expect them to be? The one thing you can be fairly certain of is that the T-SQL statement and SQL Server itself are not the problem -- that just leaves everything else.

Comment: Are you sure that @status wasn't the same as the the previous status value? Is it possible you have another query updating the status before this one gets executed?

Comment: I put the rest of the code and I'm 100% sure there was not another query which was executed before.

Comment: You do `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` to perform the update, then the `SqlDataAdapter` executes the command *again* and gets the actual result (and since you just did the update, of course you'll get the value you just set). Just use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` and use that result directly, and leave out the whole data adapter business. (Just removing the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line also works, of course.)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, it's working now